# Download email messages through Google Takeout

Tags: gmail, google-apps-email, google-takeout

I was having a look at the Google Takeout service, and one thing I noticed is that although my Google account uses Gmail (with my own domain via Google Apps for Business) when I go to takeouts Gmail isn't listed as one of the products.

I'm aware I could hook up a desktop email client to the account and backup from there, but I was wondering if there was a one click Takeout solution.

Comment: Unfortunately there is not. Gmail is listed as an "Other" project. It might be rolled into Takeout at some point, but there is no word on when: http://www.dataliberation.org/google

Comment: @OnenOnlyWalter, Is this still an issue?

Comment: @Pacerier I think so, although I think the problem is that OP says he's using a Google Apps for Business account. It might prevent Gmail from being an eligible Takeout product (I can use Takeout on my personal Gmail, but not an Apps for Business acct). Perhaps the Apps Admin can export email? But not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [GMVault](http://gmvault.org/)

The setup instructions are quite thorough and once installed you can synch (download) all your emails by a single command:

```
gmvault sync foo.bar@gmail.com
```

I believe this is as close to a one click solution as you can get right now. Good luck!